# Calling multiple CoreData key values for tableview cell display

Tags: core-data, swift, tableview

I have two strings stored with CoreData and I would like to display them both in a tableview cell.

I tried:

```
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("firstName, lastName") as? String
```

with "firstName" being one key and "lastName" being the other, but this won't compile. When I enter multiples like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("firstName") as? String
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("lastName") as? String
```

it only displays the last value (in this case "lastName") in the tableview cell.

Can anyone tell me how to display both the "firstName" and "lastName" on a tableview cell simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("firstName") as? String
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("lastName") as? String
```

Your second assignment is overwriting the first.  You need to concatenate the strings together, presumably with a space or a comma between them.

```
let firstname =  data.valueForKey("firstName") as? String
let lastname =  data.valueForKey("lastName") as? String
let separator = ", "
let label = lastname + separator + firstname
cell.textLabel.text = label
```

Comment: didn't need the comma, actually just figured it out before you posted. Thanks

Comment: ended up with: var firstName = data.valueForKey("firstName") as String
        var lastName = data.valueForKey("lastName") as String
        
        cell.textLabel.text = "\\(firstName) \\(lastName)"